# Submenu under the content in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with a submenu on this website : [removed]

When you pass your mouse over the "votre projet" tab, a submenu appears (an ul in a li, display block on the ul when li:hover, no js) in every browsers but not in IE8 (I'm using an IE10 and a real IE8 to test and the problem is in both).

At the beginning I was thinking of a problem of z-index with the submenu behind the banner image of the page, but when I hide the banner, the submenu isn't displayed at all (we can see only the border-top).

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is css filter problem which you have applied for background in old IE. Add below code inside your `head` tag.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    #header .main-nav .nav-wrapper{ filter:none}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```